# logInInBackground leaves invalid login parameters

Tags: android, parse-platform

I have been trying to use the logInInbackground feature from Parse to let users login into their profile but everytime I try to run the app and login it gives me the error that it is invalid login parameters. And yes I made sure that the username and password are equal to those in my data base. Here is my code:

```
 package edu.self.ludus;

    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.EditText;

    import com.parse.LogInCallback;
    import com.parse.ParseException;
    import com.parse.ParseUser;

    import java.util.List;

    public class LoginPage extends AppCompatActivity {

        private EditText mPasswordInput;
        private EditText mUsernameInput;
        private String mPassword;
        private String mUsername;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_login_page);
            Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
            setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

            mPasswordInput = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password_input);
            mUsernameInput = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.email_input);
            final Button loginButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.login);
            Button forgotPasswordButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.forgot_password);

            mPassword = mPasswordInput.getText().toString();
            mUsername = mUsernameInput.getText().toString();

            loginButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    ParseUser.logInInBackground(mUsername, mPassword, new LogInCallback() {
                        @Override
                        public void done(ParseUser user, ParseException e) {
                            if (user != null ){
                                Log.d("LoginPage","it was a succes");
                            }else{
                                Log.d("LoginPage","error is "+e);
                            }
                        }
                    });

                }

            });
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
loginButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

        mPassword = mPasswordInput.getText().toString();
        mUsername = mUsernameInput.getText().toString();

                ParseUser.logInInBackground(mUsername, mPassword, new LogInCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void done(ParseUser user, ParseException e) {
                        if (user != null ){
                            Log.d("LoginPage","it was a succes");
                        }else{
                            Log.d("LoginPage","error is "+e);
                        }
                    }
                });

            }

        });
    }
```

Maybe your parameters are wrong because you try to get their values before the click event

Comment: @jas bakshi! Great! if it's worked please accept the answer! :D